# In Perl, how can I determine the module version of a specific module which is already loaded?

Tags: perl, module, version

Preface: I know how to load a specific version of a module. That is not what I am after.

I'm writing a script to retrieve some text/plain data formatted as JSON from an internal server in my company. I'm using LWP for the data retrieval.

I have all of the script itself done, but have one problem.

I am writing this on RHEL5, which uses Perl 5.8.8 with LWP 5.805. According to the below page, if I want to directly output the content of the response to a file, I should use `:content_file => filename`

HOWEVER, the following is noted.

> Note that this ":content_file" option isn't supported under older
>   versions of LWP, so you should consider adding use LWP 5.66; to check
>   the LWP version, if you think your program might run on systems with
>   older versions.
>
> If you need to be compatible with older LWP versions, then use this
>   syntax, which does the same thing:
>
> `use HTTP::Request::Common;   $response = $ua->request( GET($url), $filespec );`

Since this is RHEL 5, I have to use the older LWP format, but I want to make my script so that it will use that new style instead of the older style when it is run on RHEL 6 and up, which uses a newer version of LWP that does support `:content_file`.

Hence, I need to know how to detect the module version, and more importantly, I need to know what is the earliest LWP version to support `:content_file`

Comment: Why don't you do as the comment suggests, and just use `use HTTP::Request::Common;   $response = $ua->request( GET($url), $filespec );` (regardless of version)?

Comment: That's only with older versions. I don't think the newer versions support that.

Comment: Further reading of the comments indicates that newer versions ARE backward compatible.

Comment: Even the passage you quoted seems to indicate this. But you know what, it's easy to test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version number of `LWP::UserAgent` is in the package variable`$LWP::UserAgent::VERSION`, or you can use `$LWP::VERSION` if you have written `use LWP` to load the module

However, there is no reason to use different methods for different versions of the module; the backward-compatible alternative

```
my $response = $ua->request( GET($url), $filespec )
```

will work fine on any version

Comment: Wasn't aware newer versions are backward compatible. Will give it a shot on RHEL 6 and 7 tomorrow. And if it works then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I was able to confirm this today on RHEL6. Thank you for the insightful answer.

Comment: Incidentally you also quoted this solution in your question. xD

Answer (score 6):

Since all objects extend from [`UNIVERSAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html), you can do simply `$ua->VERSION` to get the version.

It looks like `:content_file` was added in `5.66`. Compare the documentation between [5.65](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.65/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) and [5.66](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.66/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm).

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to get the version of an arbitrary module.  (The convention is for modules to have a `$VERSION` package variable, and that's what the UNIVERSAL VERSION method actually checks, but in case a module overrides the VERSION class method, calling the class method gives the authoritative answer.)

Comment: @ysth, That's wishful thinking since the CPAN indexer grabs the version from `$VERSION`, not `->VERSION`.

Comment: @ikegami that's the distro version, not a module version

Comment: @ysth, No, what I described is how it obtains the version of *modules*. The distro's version is usually one of the module's versions, but I don't see how the relates.